# OptionMenu populated with list, getting error when trying to load empty list. Work around?

Tags: python, tkinter, options-menu

Here are the lists I have:

```
a1 = [x.getName() for x in containers]
a2 = [x.getName() for x in lids]
a3 = [x.getName() for x in wicks]
a4 = [x.getName() for x in labels]
a5 = [x.getName() for x in misc]

z = []
z.extend(a1)
z.extend(a2)
z.extend(a3)
z.extend(a4)
z.extend(a5)

items = z
```

Here is the code for the OptionsMenu:

```
type_selector = OptionMenu(mainframe, add_amount_selector, *items)
```

When I try to load the program I get an error:

```
type_selector = OptionMenu(mainfrane, add_amount_selector, *items)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

It's saying that because `*items` begins empty it's missing an argument.  Is there a workaround for this?  I know I can put a random value into items and then use `items.extend(z)`, but I'd rather not put an option in the list that I do not want.

Comment: there is no sense to put `OptionMenu` if you have no values.

Comment: BTW: shorter: `items = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a4 + a5`. Or `items = []` and later `items += [x.getName() for x in containers]`, etc.

Comment: ``if not items: items = ["(no options available)"]``